# Need to click on an xpath using selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, click, webdriver, element

I have created a list of elements matching an xpath and would like to click through each successively. However, if I use the `get_attribute("href")` command I get a *'unicode' object has no attribute 'click'* error. This is because href is a string. If I don't use get_attribute and simply use this command:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div/div/div[3]/table//tr[12]/td/table//tr/td/a")
```

I get a list full of elements. I can successfully click on the first link in the list; however, when I click on the second I get this error: *'Element not
 found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up'*
I imagine that the reason that the page links I am trying to iterate through are generated via a search query into java (this is one of the href links:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$listJobsByAll1$GridView2','Page$3') )
```

One more piece of relevant information: there are only two attributes at this xpath location: href and the text.

So, given that I am dealing with a java website and only the two attributes, I am hoping someone can tell me which webdriver commands I can use to get a series of clickable static links. Beyond a specific answer, any advice on how I could have figured this out myself would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you click on a link with `selenium`, you are changing the current page. The page that you are directed to doesn't have the next element.

to get links use:

```
'.//tag/@href'
```

you can try:

```
for elem in elems:
    elem.click()
    print browser.current_url
    browser.back()
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't try that already- no reason why it wouldn't work. I'll give it a run when I get home.

Comment: So when I went back the elements were still different, thus I had to 1) count the elements, then 2) Iterate through the range of the element list, and instantiate the list every time because clicking on the i'th element.

Comment: for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div/div/div[3]/table//tr[12]/td/table//tr/td/a"):
 list.append(i)

count = len(list)-1
print count

for i in range(count):
 print i 
 target = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div/div/div[3]/table//tr[12]/td/table//tr/td/a")
 print target
 target[i].click()
 time.sleep(5)
 driver.back()
 time.sleep(5)

Comment: @user1780852, if the answer is correct and helpful to you, then you should accept it.